# Reassign Bixby button on rooted S10

Tags: root-access, buttons, samsung-galaxy-s-10, samsung-bixby

I never use Bixby on my rooted Galaxy S10e, so I would like to repurpose the Bixby button, for instance as camera shutter or to open an app of my choice.

**Question:** How to do that?

*Note: I tried following https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/1/18246255/how-to-re-program-bixby-button-samsung-galaxy-s8-s9-s10-8-note-9 but at the first step, which is to open Bixby, I am told:*

> *Bixby Voice isn't available in your country.*

*From Settings > Advanced features > Bixby key:*

> *The Bixby key setting isn't available yet. Sign in to Bixby to start using the Bixby key.*

Comment: Does useing a VPN work?

Comment: @helper: I just tried with a USA VPN server, it also says "_Bixby Voice isn't available in your country_".